# wget command unable to execute from batch file

Tags: wget

i am able to run wget command successfully from the command prompt . But when I run the same command it runs and returns to the command prompt , but it doesn't execute the command.

wget.exe -qO -t 2 -T 15 - "http://maintenance.comm/cli.php?action=add&server=tempserver&at=now&mlength=10&multiplier=MINUTES&requestor=SUPPORT&qreason=TestingScript&creds=jZW%2BcMXOwKS4ocKWuq%2B%iqC0pZvXk9Cnsnmf"

Any help on this would be appreciated .

Comment: apologies ,When I run the same command via a batch file it doesn't execute the script .

Answer (score 1):

wget only works in powershell. Lucky for you, powershell works in command prompt.

Try:

```
powershell wget -qO -t 2 -T 15 - "http://maintenance.comm/cli.php?action=add&server=tempserver&at=now&mlength=10&multiplier=MINUTES&requestor=SUPPORT&qreason=TestingScript&creds=jZW%2BcMXOwKS4ocKWuq%2B%iqC0pZvXk9Cnsnmf"
```